# Java threads reassigning a local thread variable from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, mergesort

This is a multi-threaded mergesort program. The first round of threads sort their individual parts of the array and after this they need to start joining together (ie. thread 1 joins thread 0 and thread 0 merges them together). I do not know how to get the endRow from thread 1 and pass it to thread 0 so that it can merge. Here is what i have so far:

makes all the threads:

```
public static void sort(int[] X, int numThreads){
    int n = X.length/numThreads;

    for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){
            Thread t = new Thread(new worker(X, i*n, (i+1)*n-1));
            t.start();
            threadPool.add(t);
    }

    try{
        for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){
                    threadPool.get(i).join();
        }
     }

     catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

This is what the thread runs:

```
public void run(){
        if(flag == false){
    Arrays.sort(sorted, startRow, endRow);
            flag = true;
        }
        else{
            merge();
            sorted = Arrays.copyOfRange(finalArray, startRow, endRow);
        }
}

public void merge(){

        int n = (endRow - startRow)/2 + startRow;
        int i=startRow,j=n+1,k=startRow;

        for(; i<n && j<endRow;++k){
            if( sorted[i] <= sorted[j] )
                finalArray[k]=sorted[i++];
            else
                finalArray[k]=sorted[j++];
        }

        while(i<n)
            finalArray[k++]=sorted[i++];
        while(j<endRow)
            finalArray[k++]=sorted[j++];
}
```

Comment: Nothing in this is a threadlocal, so it's all just normal object references. Either give your threads a reference to an object they can post their results into (make sure that's a threadsafe mechanism, so if two of these try to respond at once they don't step on each other), or have them post their results into an object field and have something scan through a list/array/set of all the thread objects and gather their results. Either way you'll probably also want some logic that keeps track of when they've all finished.

Comment: Note that multithreading will only improve performance of the sort if the threads are distributed across multiple processors, or if there are significant non-processor delays in the individual threads (which I don't see in a quick glance through this code).

Comment: You should look up efficient algorithms for a parallel merge - there are existing solutions for this but your approach clearly isn't going to work. The actual sort post confuses me just as much though

Answer (score 0):

What you have is separate threads acting individually. What you need are threads acting in parallel. Rather then paste code (it is substantial) here, you can download an open source project i work on that does what you want. [TymeacDSE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tymeacdse/?source=navbar)

This is taken from the documentation for the product. There are two sorts provided:

1 - Tymeac splits the large array into sorting-subsets according to the threshold you specify or a default threshold. Tymeac scatters the sorting-subsets to all available threads in the session. A Tymeac thread calls Arrays.sort() for a sorting-subset and then looks for other completed sorted-subsets with which to merge.

When the last Task finishes, Tymeac does a two array merge repeatedly on the sorted subsets from all the other Tasks until only one subset remains. This is the final array returned to the caller. (In actuality, there should only be one subset remaining after all Tasks finish which is the final array. But, you never know with multithreading and shared variables.)

The benefit of creating separate sorting subsets (with the additional memory required) is that once sorted, the sorted-subset can be merged concurrently with other sorted-subsets, which then can be merged with other sorted-subsets, etc. Therefore, there is sorting and merging going on concurrently.

This method requires fewer overall Tasks but holds memory longer. The time to complete a single request is slightly longer, but the overall throughput is much better for this Sort then for Sort below when multiple requests are working since it keeps the overall number of Tasks to a minimum.

2 - Tymeac splits the large array into sorting-subsets as above. Tymeac scatters the sorting-subsets to all available threads in the session. A Tymeac thread calls Arrays.sort() for a sorting-subset and returns that subset for the merge phase.

When the last Task finishes, Tymeac scatters the sorted-subsets for merging and gathers the merged subsets for a final merge for return to the caller. Or, if the number of partially merged subsets is large, those merged subsets are again scattered for additional merging and gathered again in the complete() method. This method is slightly faster then the Sort above for single requests especially when there are many threads to handle the spread and the array size is huge.